# How to find photos posted by users via my ios app

Tags: facebook, ipad, publish

So, i have an ipad app(Xmas window) that allows users to post some postcards in their facebook publish stream. Is it possible to find these photos?)
Thanks

Comment: The response of a post gives the id

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link.>>>http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/09/24/facebook-bug-private-messages-timeline_n_1909813.html

I never used this one so i am not sure. once we get the solution let me know to you.

Thanks